# Photoshop script odd number

Tags: photoshop-script

I need to open an image and check that the width and height are even numbers. If they are not -1px.

How do I check to see if a number is odd?

291px would = 290px

333px would = 332px

121px would = 120px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but you should be able to do this:

```
if(x&1) {x--}
```

That tests if the least significant bit is one (i.e. `x` is odd) and decrements it if so.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this.
function oddOrEven(x) {
  return ( x & 1 ) ? "odd" : "even";
}

Answer (score 1):

You could divide the original length by two, round it down with `Math.floor()` and multiply the result with two to get the desired result.

```
var wa = app.documents[0].width;
var ha = app.documents[0].height;
var wb = 2*Math.floor(wa/2);
var hb = 2*Math.floor(ha/2);
app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas(wb, hb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using modulus!

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// get original width and height
var docWidth = srcDoc.width.value;
var docHeight = srcDoc.height.value;

if (docWidth%2 == 0) alert("Image is an even number of pixels wide);
else alert("Image is an odd number of pixels wide);
```